# Function name throws error

Tags: php, function, syntax, reserved-words

I got the files that are used alongside a game called freelancer to add some advanced features. This is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'goto' (T_GOTO), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\flses.php on line 154

The only goto in that file is:

```
function goto($menue,$submenue,$string="")
{
    echo '  <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='.cFlsesAdress.'
        ?menue='.$menue.'&submenue='.$submenue.$string.'">
        </head>
        </html>';
}
```

I do not know how to rename the goto and the original person who put this out for public use is unreachable. Any help appreciated and yes, I know goto is restricted, I just don't know how to fix it.

ALSO, what is the best way to learn php? I figure if I'm making this much effort to get these files working I might as well learn it all.

Comment: FYI: You can get a quick tour here: [tour] to get a overview of this site

Comment: Yes, I know. But I posted this because I no NOTHING about php so the fixes suggested in those posts mean nothing to me. HOW do I fix this in idiot speak or how do I find the info I ned to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't name your function `goto`. It's a [reserved keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) (because it is a [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)). Rename your function and the error will go away.

Comment: How? Like I said, I know NOTHING about PHP but want to learn. The files were made public but the original creator cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

`goto` is a reserved word as you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

So you can't use it as function name. Rewrite your function to something like: `myGoto` (Best use the refactor tools of your IDE, so you can also change all function calls from that function).

Comment: No idea. Like I said I know nothing about php and the original creator put them public but cannot be reached. How do I change it to mygoto? I added my but it didn't work so I assume there's more to it than that.

Comment: OK. I figured this out sort of. IDE is the debugger so I should download the php editor and not try to freehand it in notepad like I used to write HTML way back in the day. I'll  try out jedit and see if I can figure this out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: @PatrickLaRose yes: ***I**ntegrated **d**evelopment **e**nvironment*, also see the ide section: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info With a good IDE you can rename all function calls and the function itself at the same time